# Safe to start thread using "this" in constructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <pthread.h>

class C {
private:
    int a;
    pthread_t id;

    int getA() {return a;}
    static void* threadFunction(void* arg) {((C*)arg)->getA();return 0;}

public:
    C() {
        a=2;

        pthread_create(&id,NULL,threadFunction,this);
    }
    ~C() {pthread_join(id,NULL);}

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    C c;
}
```

Is the above code safe/defined/good practise?

Should you start the thread after the constructor has returned?

Comment: The `this` in the constructor isn't the problem. The problem is the `getA()` call in `threadFunction`. You're calling a member function of an object that isn't alive yet (its constructor hasn't yet returned). Calling member functions from within a constructor is allowed, but it's *your* responsibility that all the class invariants that the member function depends on have been established at the time of the call.

Comment: "all the class invariants that the member function depends on". Is this the member variables of the class (e.g int a)?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your specific example of starting a thread in the constructor. The class members that the thread accesses have been initialized. That doesn't mean that it's always "safe", though.

One example would be a class with a virtual method that the thread invokes. Obviously, unless appropriate steps are taken place to ensure that the thread does not invoke the virtual method until the most-derived object that overrides the virtual method gets constructed, then it's not "safe", and results in undefined behavior.

And even if appropriate steps are taken, it's still may or may not be safe, depending upon what the virtual method does, or does not do.

So, as you can see, there is no universal answer whether it's "safe" or not, that will apply in every case. Each specific use case of a thread getting started from a constructor needs to be analyzed to determine if it's "safe" to do so.

But that's really no different than many other aspects of C++.